# What is the meaning of "safely add" in the check_site output

Tags: r, blogdown

With the command `check_site`, I've got two [TODO]s with "safely add" suggestions, but I don't quite understand what these two messages really mean. Do I need to add `Thumbs.db`, `.hugo_build.lock`, and `/public/`, `/resources/` to GitHub `.gitignore` file?

```
> blogdown::`check_site`()
... ...
| Checking for items you can safely ignore...
○ Found! You have safely ignored: .DS_Store
● [TODO] You can safely add to .gitignore: Thumbs.db, .hugo_build.lock
| Checking for items to ignore if you build the site on Netlify...
● [TODO] When Netlify builds your site, you can safely add to .gitignore: /public/, /resources/
```

Currently, my GitHub `.gitignore` file content looks like this:

```
.Rproj.user
.Rhistory
.RData
.Ruserdata
.Rdata
.httr-oauth
.DS_Store
```

So should I change to:

```
.Rproj.user
.Rhistory
.RData
.Ruserdata
.Rdata
.httr-oauth
.DS_Store

Thumbs.db
.hugo_build.lock

/public/
/resources/
```

Comment: "safely" means it's a recommendation, but you don't have to take it. It's only for better version control, and won't really affect your site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add these files to `.gitignore` so that they are not version controlled as they are OS/build specific.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. When you say "add these files", do you mean just add these names to the `.gitignore` file? I've also updated my questions with what's inside of `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @Y.Z. That's correct.

Comment: Right. But I'm not sure `/public/` and `/resources/` will work as this refers to system root folder and not the project folder (I think).